# HDIV 2.1.4 - IDataComposer not initialized on request, request is out of filter

Tags: java, hdiv

Our web application (Spring 3.2.13, Spring Security 2.0.5) works fine with HDIV 2.1.0, but when upgrading to HDIV 2.1.4, getting the following message:

> 13 Mar 2015 11:53:09 INFO  org.hdiv.listener.InitListener - HDIV's session created:5F0BB99E8F2B98C53AA95A9E6AF56B70
>
> 13 Mar 2015 11:53:17 DEBUG org.hdiv.urlProcessor.LinkUrlProcessor - IDataComposer not initialized on request, request is out of filter

Assume because of this message, `_HDIV_STATE_` parameter is not getting generated. Appreciate clues/inputs.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that request doesn't pass through ValidatorFilter, review it's mapping in web.xml file.